# Loop over unique subsets

Tags: r, for-loop, split

I have a problem with a for() loop running over unique site names in a data frame. The function is running, but it keeps on returning NULL result and I cannot find the mistake I must be making. $POP_RELCATEGORY is numeric. The code is:

```
 x <- split(xx, xx$LOCALITY)
    testtest <- for(i in length(unique(names(x)))){
      curr_year <- max(x[[i]]$POP_RELCATEGORY[x[[i]]$ROK == 2019])
      prev_year <- max(x[[i]]$POP_RELCATEGORY[x[[i]]$ROK == 2018])
      return(curr_year/prev_year)
    }
    testtest
```

The ideal output would be an vector consisting of curr_year/prev_year for each unique site (locality).
Thank you

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to split the data into various dataframes for this task. There are function available which can help you do to such grouped manipulation. For example, using `dplyr` you can try :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(LOCALITY) %>%
  summarise(curr_year = max(POP_RELCATEGORY[ROK == 2019]), 
            prev_year = max(POP_RELCATEGORY[ROK == 2018]), 
            result = curr_year/prev_year)
```